# Show that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{n}$ and $i\pi + \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{(z-2)^n}{n}$ are analytic continuations of one another

Tags: complex-analysis, analytic-continuation

Given the two functions:
$$f_1(z) = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{n}\ \ \text{and}\ \ f_2(z) = i\pi\ +\ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n\frac{(z-2)^n}{n}$$
I have to show that they are analytic continuations of one another.

Is this even possible since the two series have no common domain of convergence? How should I go about doing this?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The region of absolute convergence of $f_1$ is $\|z\|< 1$ and the region of absolute convergence of $f_2$ is $\|z-2\|<1$, so we are not that lucky, since these regions do not overlap over an open set. On the other hand, we may try to show that $f_1,f_2$ are restriction of the same holomorphic function $f_3$ defined over the following awkward set: $$S=\{z\in\mathbb{C}:\|z-1\|<2\}\setminus\{z\in\mathbb{C}:z=1-it,t\geq 0\},$$ containing both the previous domains of absolute convergence. The formal derivative of $f_1$ is $\frac{1}{1-z}$ and the formal derivative of $f_2$ is $\frac{1}{1-z}$: at least the hunt makes sense. The formal primitive of $\frac{1}{1-z}$ is $-\log(1-z)$ and such function has a holomorphic determination over $S$, such that $-\log(1-2)=\pi i=f_2(2)$ and $-\log(1-0)=0=f_1(0)$. I bet you can finish from here.

Comment: Who is $ f_{3} $?

Comment: @JacobS.: a simultaneous extension of both $f_1$ and $f_2$ over a larger domain.

Comment: Why is the ray $ \{ z \in \textbf{C}: z = 1 - it, t \geq 0 \} $ removed from the circle $ \{ z\in \textbf{C}: \vert z-1 \vert < 2 \} $ ?

Comment: You wrote: $ -log (1-2) = \pi i$, It is right?

I believe that: $ -log (1-2) =- \pi i$

Comment: @JacobS., no, it is right. We choose a branch of the logarithm with such determination. It has to be holomorphic, so the larger domain must not enclose a loop around $1$. That is the reason for the removal of the ray.

Comment: $ \int_{C} \dfrac{1}{1-z} = -log(1-z)$,  where $C$ is either of the two circles, is that correct?

Comment: @JacobS. No, $\oint_{\gamma}\frac{dz}{1-z}$ is a number, not a function. What I am saying is $\frac{1}{1-z}=\frac{d}{dz}\left[-\log(1-z)\right]$.